# Item selected on Spinner be global - Android

Tags: android, spinner, global

i have two Activitys , where on "SecondActivity" have a Spinner , the selected item on Spinner is sent to "TerceiraActivity" .

But , i wanna make the itemselected on Spinner to variable global , so this way i'll put this variable in other class , called "BD.class"

Here is "SecondActivity"

```
package br.exemplosqlite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements   AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    //referencia a Spinner
    //Spinner coligada;

    //final TextView nome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvNome);
    //final TextView sobrenome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvSobrenome);
    //final Spinner pday = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    final Spinner spcoligada = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.coligada);








    //spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter adaptercoligada= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.coligada, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spcoligada.setAdapter(adaptercoligada);



    Button ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnok);







    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //chamada para a nova Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, TerceiraActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("coligada", spcoligada.getSelectedItem().toString());


            //intent.putExtra("nomePessoa", nome.getText().toString());
            //intent.putExtra("sobrenomePessoa", sobrenome.getText().toString());
            //intent.putExtra("day", pday.getSelectedItem().toString());










            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}




@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
      }
```

this is the "TerceiraActivity"

```
package br.exemplosqlite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

public class TerceiraActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_terceira);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String parametro = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("nomePessoa");
    //String psobrenome = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("sobrenomePessoa");
    //String ppday = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("day");

    String pcoligada = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("coligada");











    //TextView nome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvNome);
    //TextView sobrenome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvSobrenome);
    TextView coligadas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spvcoligada);






    //nome.setText("Olá " + parametro + ", Tem de fazer a barba " );
    coligadas.setText("coliga escolhida : "+ pcoligada);


}


    }
```

This is "BD.class"

```
package br.exemplosqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

 public class BD {
private SQLiteDatabase bd;

public BD(Context context){
    BDCore auxBd = new BDCore(context);
    bd = auxBd.getWritableDatabase();
}


public void inserir(Produtos produtos){
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("item", produtos.getItem());
    valores.put("coligada", produtos.getColigada());
    valores.put("filial", produtos.getFilial());


    bd.insert("produtos2", null, valores);
}


public void atualizar(Produtos produtos){
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();

    valores.put("item", produtos.getItem());
    valores.put("coligada", produtos.getColigada());
    valores.put("filial", produtos.getFilial());

    bd.update("produtos2", valores, "_id = ?", new String[]{""+produtos.getId()});
}


public void deletar(Produtos produtos){
    bd.delete("produtos2", "_id = "+produtos.getId(), null);
}


public List<Produtos> buscar(){
    List<Produtos> list = new ArrayList<Produtos>();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id", "item", "coligada","filial"};

    Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("select * from produtos2",null);

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do{

            Produtos p = new Produtos();
            p.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            p.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
            p.setColigada(cursor.getString(2));
            p.setFilial(cursor.getString(3));
            list.add(p);

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return(list);
}
             }
```

Comment: make that variable static so that you can access it with class name

Comment: on "TerceiraActivity" when i change to public , i receive the error "Modifier Static not allowed here " 

static String pcoligada = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("coligada");

Comment: you can save it in shared preference then

Comment: Vivek , how can i save it in shared preference ?

Comment: you can check online on how to save integer/string in shared prefferences

Comment: you could make to me , to me learn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the Solution , creating a Global Class , and assign the value of my Spinner.toString();

Thanks for all :D

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in shared preferences.Just copy the following code in a new class named AppSharedPreferences

```
public class AppSharedPreferences {
private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
private static AppSharedPreferences appSharedPrefrence;

public AppSharedPreferences(Context context) {
    this.appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
}

public static AppSharedPreferences getsharedprefInstance(Context con) {
    if (appSharedPrefrence == null)
        appSharedPrefrence = new AppSharedPreferences(con);
    return appSharedPrefrence;
}

public SharedPreferences getAppSharedPrefs() {
    return appSharedPrefs;
}

public void setAppSharedPrefs(SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs) {
    this.appSharedPrefs = appSharedPrefs;
}

public SharedPreferences.Editor getPrefsEditor() {
    return prefsEditor;
}

public void Commit() {
    prefsEditor.commit();
}

public void clearallSharedPrefernce() {
    prefsEditor.clear();
    prefsEditor.apply();
}
public void setSession(String session)
{
    this.prefsEditor=appSharedPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString("session",session);
    prefsEditor.apply();
}
public String getSession()
{
    return appSharedPrefs.getString("session","");
}
```

}

and to use this in your class create it's object like this
first define an object like this

```
AppSharedPreferences appSharedPreferences;
```

and then instantiate it like this

```
appSharedPreferences = AppSharedPreferences.getsharedprefInstance(YourActivityName.this);
```

and then to save value call the setter method

```
appSharedPreferences.setSession(your value);
```

and similarly use the getter method to get value back

Comment: Hey friend , when i put this

{
        return appSharedPrefs.getString("session", "");
    }
}

i receive a error "Return outside Method "

Comment: I forgot to change the return type of get method . Change Boolean to string in that

Comment: Okay , now is saying to me Install de API 9 , i'll install and update you friend.

Comment: It has nothing to do with api

Comment: Hey vivek , i must say , Java is crazy hahaha , i think that is must be a simple way to pick the item selected and use where i want , hahaha

Comment: Not , because i 'm trying install API 9 , method apply is saying to install .

Comment: Hey Vivek , API instaled , now i'll try your code , only one thing , is possible use sharedpreferences with spinner ?

Comment: Vivek , i dont understand ,  i must put this "AppSharedPreferences appSharedPreferences;" where ? Second or TerceiraActivity ?

Comment: Man that is just defining variable . Do it at class level